# How to resize image to fit UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

How to fit `UIImage` into the cell of `UITableView`, UITableViewCell (?).

Do you `addSubview` to `cell` or is there a way to resize `cell.image` or the `UIImage` before it is assigned to `cell.image` ?

I want to keep the cell size default (whatever it is when you init with zero rectangle) and would like to add icon like pictures to each entry. Images are slightly bigger than the cell size (table row size).

I think the code looks like this (from top of my head):

```
UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] imageWithName:@"bart.jpg"];
cell = ... dequeue cell in UITableView data source (UITableViewController ...)
cell.text = @"bart";
cell.image = image;
```

What do I need to do to resize the image to fit the cell size?
I've seen something like:

```
UIImageView * iview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
iview.frame = CGRectMake(...); // or something similar
[cell.contentView addSubview:iview]
```

The above will add image to cell and I can calculate the size to fit it, however:

1. I'm not sure if there is a better
   way, isn't it too much overhead to
   add `UIImageView` just to resize the
   `cell.image` ?
2. Now my label (`cell.text`) needs to be
   moved as it is obscured by image,
   I've seen a solution where you just
   add the text as a label:

Example:

```
UILabel * text = [[UILable alloc] init];
text.text = @"bart";
[cell.contentView addSubview:iview];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
// not sure if this will position the text next to the label
// edited original example had [cell addSubview:label], maybe that's the problem
```

Could someone point me in correct direction?

**EDIT**: Doh `[cell.contentview addSubview:view]` not `[cell addSubview:view]` maybe I'm supposed to look at this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...;
    CGRect frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    myLabel.text = ...;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site posts code](http://blog.logichigh.com/2008/06/05/uiimage-fix/) on rescaling a `UIImage*`. You could play with the scaling to get the right ratio for the `UIImage*` you are using, to scale it down.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the apple devloper center, there is a video about scaling images for table views.  It is more focused on performance issues and talks lots about threading, but he does shows some sample code used to resize images.

Video name: "Effective iPhone App Development - Part 2" about 30 mins in.